# Run JavaScript Function when the Submit Button has Been Pushed, not on Drop-Down Selection?

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a random number generator type of project, and the following code below has a double-dropdown that once chosen, calls the function tied to whatever you have chosen from the list of options in the drop-down. This works fine and all, but I would much rather have the strings generate after the submit/generate button is pushed. Is there anyway to make this happen?

See code below as well as a live example at http://hawkgen.com/gen/

```
   <!-- The first select list -->
    <select name="slist1" onchange="SList.getSelect('slist2', this.value);">
     <option>- - -</option>
     <option value="amazon">Amazon</option>
     <option value="apple">Apple</option>
     <option value="keurig">Keurig</option>
     <option value="nike">Nike</option>
    </select>
    <!-- Tags for the seccond dropdown list, and for text-content -->
    <span id="slist2"></span> <div id="scontent"></div>
    <div id="display">Hello World (placeholder text, code will generate here.)</div>


  <script><!--
    /* Script Double Select Dropdown List, from: coursesweb.net/javascript/ */
    var SList = new Object();             // JS object that stores data for options

    // HERE replace the value with the text you want to be displayed near Select
    var txtsl2 = '';

    /*
     Property with options for the Seccond select list
     The key in this object must be the same with the values of the options added in the first select
     The values in the array associated to each key represent options of the seccond select
    */
    SList.slist2 = {
     "amazon": ['Kindle Fire HD', 'Kindle Charger', 'Kindle Fire HDX'],
     "apple": ['MacBook', 'iMac', 'iPhone', 'iPad'],
     "keurig": ['Platinum', 'Vue'],
     "nike": ['Fuel Band']
    };


    /*
     Property with text-content associated with the options of the 2nd select list
     The key in this object must be the same with the values (options) added in each Array in "slist2" above
     The values of each key represent the content displayed after the user selects an option in 2nd dropdown list
    */

SList.scontent = {
 "Kindle Fire HD": 'kindlefirehd',
 "Kindle Charger": 'kindlecharge',
 "Kindle Fire HDX": 'kindlefirehdx',
 "MacBook": 'macbook',
 "iMac": 'imac',
 "iPhone": 'iphone',
 "iPad": 'ipad',
 "Platinum": 'platinum',
 "Vue": 'vue',
 "FuelBand": 'fuelband'
};





        /* From here no need to modify */

    // function to get the dropdown list, or content
    SList.getSelect = function(slist, option) {
      document.getElementById('scontent').innerHTML = '';           // empty option-content

      if(SList[slist][option]) {
        // if option from the last Select, add text-content, else, set dropdown list
        if(slist == 'scontent'){;
var selected = SList[slist][option];
functions[selected]();
}
        else if(slist == 'slist2') {
          var addata = '<option>- - -</option>';
          for(var i=0; i<SList[slist][option].length; i++) {
            addata += '<option value="'+SList[slist][option][i]+'">'+SList[slist][option][i]+'</option>';
          }

          document.getElementById('slist2').innerHTML = txtsl2+' <select name="slist2" onchange="SList.getSelect(\'scontent\', this.value);">'+addata+'</select>';
        }
      }
      else if(slist == 'slist2') {
        // empty the tag for 2nd select list
        document.getElementById('slist2').innerHTML = '';
      }
    }

    var functions = {

        kindlefirehd: function(){
    var secondPossible = 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSVWY123456';
    var firstPossible = '123456';
    var firstLength = 1;
    var secondLength = 2;

    var firstString = Array.apply(null, new Array(firstLength)).map(function () {
    return firstPossible[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstPossible.length)];
    }).join('');
    var secondString = Array.apply(null, new Array(secondLength)).map(function () {
    return secondPossible[Math.floor(Math.random() * secondPossible.length)];
    }).join('');

    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML='D0FB A0A0 343' + firstString + ' 0A' + secondString

        },
        kindlecharge: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        kindlefirehdx: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        macbook: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        imac: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        iphone: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        ipad: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        platinum: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        vue: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        fuelband: function(){window.alert("func1 called")}
    }





    </script>
```

Comment: Is jQuery not an option?

Comment: It is most definitely an option, I just have not yet dipped my head into it much.

Comment: I suggest you look at knockout because it will make your life so much easier!

Comment: I would put together one, but I'm still trying to understand what is this code is doing :)

Comment: Take a look at the live example, not sure if that will help wrap your head around it. It is a bit messy, my apology, but basically it is a double drop-down that then calls a function with the same value as the drop-down option chosen.

Comment: I'm on it :) looked at example a few times

Comment: What exactly do you want help with?  The task is to move some code out of the drop-down change event handler and put it in a click handler for the submit button.

Comment: What strings need to be generated and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered without testing and missed an important part. Leaving original answer below.

I set up an example of one way to do this at

http://bsoist.cloudvent.net/so/23096335.html

===ORIGINAL ANSWER===

One approach would be ...

Replace this

```
<select name="slist1" onchange="SList.getSelect('slist2', this.value);">
```

with this

```
<select name="slist1" onchange="setOption(this.value);">
```

and then add the button

```
<input type="submit" onsubmit="void(SList.getSelect('slist2'));">
```

edit the Slist.getSelect function by changing this

```
SList.getSelect = function(slist, option) {
```

to this

```
SList.getSelect = function(slist) {
```

create a global variable called option instead, and then add this function.

```
function setOption(value) {
    option = value;
}
```

Comment: I didn't work through the whole thing. I am working on a complete solution now.

Comment: I am stuck at the global option variable, what would that look like, and where would the last function go?

Comment: You're very welcome. If you get a chance, perhaps you could choose my answer.

Comment: Just did, I forgot to click the check and had the vote button clicked the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

I have got [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wF8gS/1/) so far with knockout js and jQuery.

Its fairly elagant. The reasons why:

- It turns your JSON list into usable objects with properties
- All bindings (element updates) are taken care of by knockout
- The previous point allows you to write the code that matters leaving it clean

I use a view model to take care of all the code, knockout takes care of the bindings:

```
var viewModel = function () {
  var self = this;

    self.makes = ko.observableArray($.map(makesArray, function (item) { return new makeModel(item); }));
    self.selectedMake = "";

    self.subMakes = ko.observable(null);
    self.subMakesArray = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.selectedSubMake = "";

    self.firstListBoxChange = function () {
        self.subMakesArray(self.selectedMake.subMakes);
    }

    self.submitSomething = function () {
     // do something here   
    }

}
```

With the `data-bind` you can have anything fire off an event to do something:

```
data-bind="options: makes,optionsText: 'name', value: selectedMake,event: { change: firstListBoxChange() }"
```

This is in the first `select` and when it is changed will fire off the `firstListBoxChange()` function in the view model.

```
data-bind="click: submitSomething"
```

This is in the button, and fires of `submitSomething`. However, the first `select` event can be mimicked in the second `select` if you want that one to fire off an event.